# Start Android SDK Remotely

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-10.04, android-sdk-tools, x11-forwarding

I have to start android sdk with gui via ssh. I have installed Xming Server on my local machine and enabled X11 forwarding in shell settings. Remote machine has Ubuntu OS 10.04, 32-bit.

When I start

```
  ./android sdk
```

It throws me with following errors:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:376)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

How do I start sdk with gui remotely? Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Android SDK manager - it breaks if your `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec` option.
Make sure that your fstab entry for `/tmp` looks like this:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid 0 0
```

If your current line contains `noexec`, remove it or you will see this cryptic error.